# C++ Delete nodes after another in Single Linked List

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is check if node after value is specific number and if is, then delete previoues node.
Something like:

1,2,3,4,5,4
if next node number is 4 then delete this node.
1,2,3,4,5,4 -> 1,2,4,4

```
node* temp = head;
while (head != NULL) {
    if (head->next->number == 4) {
        delete temp;
    }
    head = head->next;
}
```

Struggling at this moment as compiler crashes.

Comment: You need to include what errors you're getting.

Comment: Process returns 255 @CodeBlocks.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you're compiler is probably crashing because you check if `head !=NULL` but then you call  `head->next->number`. So `head` might not be NULL, but you cannot guarantee `head->next !=NULL` unless you explicitly check.

Comment: check if (head->next == NULL) ?

Answer (score 1):

You delete the head before you advance it:

```
node *temp = NULL;
while (head->next != NULL) {
    if (head->next->number == 4) {
        temp = head;
    }
    if ( temp == NULL ){
        head = head->next;
    }
    else{ 
        head = head->next->next;
        delete temp;
        temp= NULL:
    }
}
```